# increased Page loading speed with gallery widget

Tags: loading, impresspages

I am testing IP4.4.2 on localhost and planning my upgrade strategy (from ip3.x). One thing I have noticed is the very long page loading times with the gallery widget.

I am using the NET tab in Firebug to get the speeds.
Typical results;
(1) Pages with text and photos  75 to 120 ms
(2) Page with 4 images in gallery 2.86 sec
(3) page with 9 images in gallery 6.37 sec

These are not big images in the gallery, pages with just text and images have much larger images and load quickly.

It is not that the images load gradually, nothing happens for the full 6.37 secs then the pages loads completely.

I am using the Air theme and I have used images boarders and shadows.

Any ideas why there is such a long loading time?

Alan

Comment: Have a look at a demo. To my oppinion both pages load equaly:

http://4025.cloud.impresspages.org/home

http://4025.cloud.impresspages.org/lorem-ipsumy

Comment: I deleted the gallery from the slow page and now the page loads in 81ms. I will try again with image pre-cropped to 200px x 200px

Comment: I reloaded the gallery widget with all pre-cropped images (9 images), now the page loads in 1.6sec.   According to Firebug my pages loads 462kb and your cloud page (which loads in 161ms) loads 207kb.  So it looks like i need to be careful of the total kb to be loaded.  Alan

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it appears it was my localhost set up that was the problem. When I first installed IP I did not have mod_rewrite activated.  I activated mod_rewrite later but did not change the IP set up.  I still had index.php in the site urls and did not  realise.

Now I have re-installed the system with the mod-rewrite working properly and the pages with the gallery widget install at similar speeds to the other pages.

I don't know why the gallery pages were slow in the set up site with the mod-rewrite problem, but now all is working properly, and I have the proper urls !!!

Alan